# Proxy auto login using domain credential

Tags: proxy, authentication, ldap, squid

I am using `pfSense` with `squid proxy`, linked and configured with `LDAP` to my win server 2016.

Every user is allowed to navigate but I need to log urls based on username.
Proxy authentication popup works fine but users struggles to enter the same credentials twice..

Is possible to authenticate user automatically to proxy with a script or policy without prompt popup?

EDIT: My domain's PCs are all Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory domain auto-login uses **Kerberos**, which in HTTP (including HTTP proxies) is also known as '**SPNEGO**' or '**Negotiate**' authentication. See Squid documentation:

- https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/WindowsActiveDirectory
- https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Kerberos
- https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/NegotiateAuthentication

There may be some cases where clients cannot use Kerberos – this should be *rare,* but in those situations auto-login can use NTLM instead. Squid can do this as well (in fact with proper configuration it can handle both Kerberos *and* NTLM):

- https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/WindowsActiveDirectory
- https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Ntlm

Comment: do you have any example for windows? links for linux-only. The only one for windows is broken

Comment: The links are for configuring the proxy server, not client machines.